# how to detect screen casters android, detect tap pressure

Tags: android, detect, tap, pressure

I developed an app that is fun to play with but there are some naughty people who are vandalizing fun of other people by using different type of **screen casters** and then playing with automated scripts and cheating users.

[here is a link](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) to a very famous screen caster. but is there any way to detect it? I think I have read somewhere that I can get tap pressure on accelerometer in android.

please help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int)

Comment: you can go to link and there is a method on MotionEvent to detect pressure but haven't tried it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html An example related to but not exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Sample Application

```
package com.pressure.detection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 private TextView tvConsole;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 findViewById(R.id.root_layout).setOnTouchListener(this);

 tvConsole = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtConsole);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mEvent) {
    tvConsole.setText("Pressure: "+mEvent.getPressure() );


 System.out.println("Hardware X " + mEvent.getXPrecision()
  * mEvent.getX());
 System.out.println("Hardware Y " + mEvent.getYPrecision()
  * mEvent.getY());
 return super.onTouchEvent(mEvent);
    }

}
```