# android-- how to use the measure getPressure

Tags: android, view

I have a problem with how to use the measure-- getPressure of the MotionEvent. I want to measure the pressure that is applied to the screen when a user touches it. Can anybody give me some sample or so.

One more question:
   the return of `getPressure:1.0` is defined by the strongest press or by the device.

Comment: Have you seen this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293294/how-to-detect-screen-casters-android-detect-tap-pressure

Answer (score 1):

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mPressure = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);// Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of a particular sensor.

public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
float millibars_of_pressure = event.values[0];//use the pressure value
 }
```

Comment: this is the pressure sensor's usage,not exactly what i ask about.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MySensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    private     SensorManager   mSensorManager;
    private     Sensor          mPressure;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mSensorManager      = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mPressure           = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);

}

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float millibars_of_pressure = event.values[0];
    Log.e("sensorValues",String.valueOf(millibars_of_pressure));
    }

     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mPressure, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```